# Extracting List of coordinates from string

Tags: python, list, parsing, coordinates, geojson

Hello Iv been at this all day but have ran into a problem.

I am reading in GeoJson file and trying to extract the coordinates so that I can later iterate throughout them to determine the size of my window to redraw the polygons, represented by a list of coordinates. 
Each polygon may have 4 - x coordinate pairs. 
When I read in the GeoJson I get a list containing only 1 element for each polygon instead of a list with a list of coordinates. I believe this is because the list reads: `[[[-76.2671328, 38.4506304], [-76.2669856, 38.4505256], [-76.2668385, 38.4503701], [-76.2667281, 38.4502182], [-76.2664568, 38.4499759], [-76.2661993, 38.4497843], [-76.2660108, 38.4497192]...]]`
and there are multiple sets of [[]] which make the list think there is one element inside..?

So then i tried converting the list of coordinate to a string so I could remove the extra [[]] and extract the coordinate pairs and turn them back into a list. Here is the code:

```
import json
import re

with open('landareas.json') as f:
    landareas = json.load(f)

coordinates = []
polygons = []
for feature in landareas['features']:
    polygons.append(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])

print len(polygons)
for polygon in polygons:
    #print type(polygon)
    #print len(polygon)
    string =  str(polygon)  
    newCords = string[2:len(string)-1]
    print newCords
    coordinates.append(re.findall('[(.+?)]', newCords))

for coordinate in coordinates:
    print coordinate
    print
```

So now when i do this all i get back is:

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

With all the numbers stripped out.. :(!

If someone could please help me out in a method to exact the coordinates into a list of coordinates for each polygon so that I can loop through a list of polygons with each containing a list of their coordinates, that would be greatly apprcieated!

My initial error which started this was:

```
File "polygon_LatLong_xy.py", line 33, in <module>
    for x,y in polygons[CORDINATES]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not utterable
```

from this python script:

```
import turtle as t
import json

RCID = 0
CORDINATES= 1

with open('landareas.json') as f:
    landareas = json.load(f)

polygons = []
for feature in landareas['features']:
    polygons.append([feature['properties']['RCID'], feature['geometry']['coordinates'] ])

map_width = 400
map_height = 400

minx = 180
maxx = -180
miny = 90
maxy = -90

for x,y in polygons[CORDINATES]:
    if x < minx: minx = x
    elif x > maxx: maxx = x
    if y < miny: miny = y
    elif y > maxy: maxy = y

dist_x = maxx - minx
dist_y = maxy - miny

x_ratio = map_width / dist_x
y_ratio = map_height / dist_y

def convert(point):
    lon = point[0]
    lat = point[1]
    x = map_width - ((maxx - lon) * x_ratio)
    y = map_height - ((maxy - lat) * y_ratio)
    #Python turtle graphics start in the middle of the screen 
    #so we must offset the points so the are centered
    x = x - (map_width/2)
    y = y -(map_height/2)
    return [x,y]

t.up()
first_pixel = None
for point in polygons[CORDINATES]:
    pixel = convert(point)
    if not first_pixel:
        first_pixel = pixel
    t.goto(pixel)
    t.down()
t.goto(first_pixel)
t.write(str(polygons[RCID]), align="center", font=("Arial",16,"bold"))
t.up()
t.done()
```

If its any help here is an excerpt from the geoJson file:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon", 
        "coordinates": [ <--- note the 
          [ <----------------two sets of brackets? could this be why?              
            [
              -76.0220181, 
              38.1321203
            ], 
            [
              -76.0219133, 
              38.1321847
            ], 
            [
              -76.0232178, 
              38.1312463
            ], 
            [
              -76.0230198, 
              38.1312923
            ], 
            [
              -76.0220181, 
              38.1321203
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }, 
      "type": "Feature", 
      "properties": {
        "TXTDSC": "                                                                                ", 
        "RCID": 3918, 
        "PRIM": 3, 
        "NINFOM": "                                                                                ", 
        "SORIND": "                                                                                ", 
        "RECDAT": "                                                                                ", 
        "AGEN": 550, 
        "GRUP": 1, 
        "SORDAT": "                                                                                ", 
        "OBJL": 71, 
        "NOBJNM": "                                                                                ", 
        "INFORM": "                                                                                ", 
        "LNAM": "0226088C104B1046", 
        "STATUS": "                                                                                ", 
        "RECIND": "                                                                                ", 
        "SCAMAX": null, 
        "NTXTDS": "                                                                                ", 
        "CONDTN": null, 
        "FIDS": 4166, 
        "SCAMIN": null, 
        "FIDN": 143396939, 
        "RVER": 1, 
        "OBJNAM": "                                                                                "
      }
    },
```

Comment: Also, you should look into why the system thought polygons[CORDINATES] was an integer instead of an array. I made a theory about what was wrong in my answer, but that could explain a lot about what is going on :).

Comment: I agree and that was how i wound up converting what should have been a list of coordinate pairs into a string with coordinate pairs ha

Comment: OK, so after you make separate strings of coordinate pairs. Take out the parentheses by `str = str.replace("(", "")` for both parentheses and then split by the comma. You should have your lists, and not get the iterable error

Comment: Removing the brackets with `str.replace("[", "")` will result in all brackets being removed. Repeating this with the other bracket will leave me with as string of number with commas after each number, which is no good for distinguishing pairs. `[[[-76.2671328, 38.4506304], [-76.2669856, 38.4505256], [-76.2668385, 38.4503701]]] ` into `-76.2671328, 38.4506304, -76.2669856, 38.4505256, -76.2668385, 38.4503701` but I guess I could `str.replace("],", "|")` or another charter to distinguish pairs and then spitting on the same charter.

Comment: Ah, your problem is that you have everything in one string. Alright this is what you do. First, you need to make a string array by splitting the string by `","`. THEN do the replacing.

Comment: If you don't have the coordinates separated by commas, well, then you make a program which searches for every beginning bracket, goes until the end bracket, and copies the inner code into one element of a string array

Comment: The long original string, as two sets of commas. One to separate x,y and the other separate [ pair ], [pair]. Its just coming down to a bunch of string manipulation which i was trying to avoid. I thought there would be a better way.

Comment: But the string manipulation takes barely a few codes! You can do it in a max of four lines

Comment: Im going to give it a shot. The reason I wanted to avoid string parsing is that the Geodata is rather large and Im only looking at a small area 100x100 mile of the Chesapeake Bay and close to 1,500,500 pairs. This project will span the entire cost east coast. Essentially what I'm trying to do is have converted shape files to geojson to extract the polygon structures and redraw them in an x, y plane.

Comment: I'm going to leave this issue open for a few more days..see if anyone else has any recommendations.

Comment: Alriight, sorry I couldn't find another soluution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not complete sure about your code, but I think your problem is that when you get the string value of the coordinates (in the `polygons.append(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])` and `coordinates.append(re.findall('[(.+?)]', newCords))`, you don't convert them into a list first.

Let's say we have a string `c = "1, 2"` You can do `biglist.append(c.split(","))`

One more thing that might help is that you make a set of coordinates for each polygon.

```
#Make a condition that tells the program when to search for the next polygon
polygons = []
polygon = []
for x in landareas['features']:
    if polygonDone:
        polygons.append(polygon)
        del polygon[:]
    else:
        polygon.append(x['geometry']['coordinates'].split(","))
```

Comment: When I call `feature['geometry']['coordinates']` it returns a on object of type list.

Comment: Is every single value a string? If not, you might need to find a way to iterate over only the types you want

Comment: no the coordinates are not strings. I just turned them into one so I could manipulate the now string of coordinates.

Comment: Did you make separate strings of coordinates or one huge string?

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about re i was able to come up with this bit of code that found the x,y pairs and turn them back into a list of x,y pairs, though they are still represented as a string.

```
for feature in landareas['features']:
    string_listof_cords = str(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
    #print string_cords
    string_listof_cords = string_listof_cords.replace(",", "")
    print(re.findall(r'\D\d*\.\d*\s\d*\.\d*', string_listof_cords))
```

However, in my searching I found a better way to do what I was initially trying todo, manipulate polygons from shape files, and have such aborted this method all together. Thanks for the help @ytpillai

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution :)